# Crear una nueva instancia de una clase inyectada con @Autowired en cada llamada

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, dependencyinjection

Tengo una clase FacturaService que tiene inyectada otra clase MailService.

A través del método "enviarFactura" recibo una factura en pdf y la envío por correo electrónico.

El problema viene cuando recibo muchas llamadas seguidas, porque al parecer las llamadas se hacen más rápido de lo que se tarda en adjuntar los pdfs al email (Esto es solo una teoría que tengo), y el resultado es que se envía una misma factura a varios clientes. Y luego otra factura a otros tantos clientes, y así. (Quiero destacara que el proceso de envío de facturas por mail funciona bien cuando se hacen las llamadas una a una)

He intentado anotar tanto la clase FacturaService como la clase EmailService con @Scope("prototype"), pero no ha servido para nada.

CLASE FACTURASERVICE

```
@Service
public class FacturaService {

    @Autowired
    private FacturaRepository facturaRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FacturaValidation facturaValidation;
    @Autowired
    private ClienteService clienteService;
    @Autowired
    private LecturaRepository lecturaRepository;
    @Autowired
    private LineaDetalleService lineaDetalleService;
    @Autowired
    private LineaDetalleRepository lineaDetalleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private EmpresaService empresaService;
    @Autowired
    private RemesaService remesaService;
    @Autowired 
    private EmailService emailService;
    @Autowired
    private Utils utils;

    public Boolean sendFactura(int id, MailFacturaDTO dto) {

        try {
            Factura factura = getById(id);
            Cliente cliente = factura.getIdCliente();
            String destinatario = cliente.getEmail();
        
            String remitente = "Remitente";
            if(dto.getRemitente() != null)
                remitente = dto.getRemitente();

            String asunto = "Tu factura de " + Utils.traduceMes(factura.getFecha().getMonth()) + " de " + remitente;
            if(dto.getAsunto() != null)
                asunto = dto.getAsunto();

            String nombre = cliente.getNombre();
            if(cliente.getApellidos() != null && !cliente.getApellidos().isBlank())
                nombre = nombre + " " + cliente.getApellidos();
        
        
            String template = "envioFactura";
            File file = utils.convert(dto.getFile(), "factura.pdf");
        
            Map<String,Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put("nombre", nombre);
            props.put("remitente", remitente);

            if(destinatario != null && !destinatario.isBlank()) {
            
                emailService.send(props, destinatario, file, template, nombre, asunto);
                factura.setEstado(EstadoFactura.ENVIADO);
                facturaRepository.save(factura);
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Y LA CLASE EMAILSERVICE

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired 
    private TemplateTool templateTool;
    @Autowired 
    private MailTool mailTool;

    public void send(Map<String, Object> props, String email, File file, String template, String projectName, String subject) throws Exception {

        List<String> emailList = new ArrayList<>();
        emailList.add(email);       
    
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        files.add(file);
    
        String render = templateTool.render(template, props);
    
        DataBuilder mailData = Data.builder().body(render).from("no-reply@dominio.com")
            .fromName(projectName)
            .subject(subject)
            .fileList(files)
            .targetList(emailList);
    
    Data mailDataBuild = mailData.build();
    mailTool.send(mailDataBuild, null);
    Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
}
```

}

Comment: encimad e los métodos de un service, pon un `@Transactional`, te adjunto documentación sobre este maravilloso decorador [aqui](https://www.apascualco.com/spring-boot/spring-transactional/), leelo bien todo, ya que puede que te interese algo de lo que explica, lo dejo a tu criterio.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he probado y me sigue pasando lo mismo. Ahora estoy intentando hacerlo convirtiendo a los métodos implicados en asíncronos, pero tampoco estoy tniendo mucho éxito.

Comment: Necesitamos ver más código. Tal vez el problema no esté en `EmailService` sino en alguna otra instancia de algo que estés reutilizando, TemplateTool, MailTool, MailFacturaDTO.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Después de muchas pruebas sin éxito, como por ejemplo tratar de que las llamadas a métodos implicados en el proceso de envío de correos fueran asíncronas, alguien que sabe mucho más que yo (mi jefe) lo ha solucionado.

La solución ha sido que en lugar de...

```
File file = utils.convert(dto.getFile(), "factura.pdf");
```

Ahora hago...

```
File file = utils.convert(dto.getFile(), "factura_R" + factura.getNumero() + ".pdf");
```

Con lo cual, se está generando un archivo pdf distinto para cada llamada y ahora una llamada no machaca el archivo que todavía se estaba generando para la llamada anterior.

Qué fácil ha sido la solución, y qué difícil y frustrante me resultaba a mí.

Gracias a todo por intentar ayudarme.